# Mock same interface as 2 different types

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, moq

I have an interface `IMyInterface` that I am mocking in a unit test using moq.

```
Mock<IMyInterface> firstMockedObject = new Mock<IMyInterface>();
Mock<IMyInterface> secondMockedObject = new Mock<IMyInterface>();
```

The unit under test has a register method that looks like this:

`public void RegisterHandler(Type type, IHandler handler)`

and then a handle method:

`public void Handle(IMyInterface objectToHandle)`

What I am trying to test is that I can regiester 2 handlers for 2 different implementations of `IMyInterface` and that the Handle method correctly selects which one to use:

```
UnitUnderTest.RegisterHAndler(firstMockedObject.Object.GetType(), handler1);
UnitUnderTest.RegisterHAndler(seconMockedObject.Object.GetType(), handler2);
```

The problem is both mocked objects are of the same type. Is there some way to force Moq to generate 2 mocks of the same interface as different types?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Createtwo interfaces that derive from your interface. Use them for the mocks. The type of each one will be the mocked interface type:

```
public interface IMockOne : IMyInterface { };
public interface IMockTwo : IMyInterface { };


var firstMockedObject = new Mock<IMockOne>();
var secondMockedObject = new Mock<IMockTwo>();
```

This allows you to not implement a whole class for mocking, but to use `moq` to create dynamic mocks.

Comment: When you point that out, it seems so obvious! This was exactly what I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can create your own mock implementation for this test.
Like

```
public class MockOne : IMyInterface {}
public class MockTwo : IMyInterface {}
```

Comment: Noting that members must be virtual if you are mocking a concrete class with Moq.

Comment: @stuartd I suggest not to use Moq and create own mock classes. If necessary, you can also track calls.

Comment: @Valentin This completely defeats the use of a dynamic mocking framework, which consists in dynamically creating mocks from ther interfaces. If you do this, you'll have to implement yourself the whole interface in both classes. And if you do so, you're not using Moq, but writing the code by hand.